# Plotly Axis Position using CSS

Tags: javascript, css, axis, plotly

I have three axis and I am trying to adjust their position by using CSS but it does not work as you can see in the jsfiddle.

I would like the first two axis on the left and the third one on the right. If possible I would like the third one with a greater height but a smaller width. How can I adjust it ?

Here is the code (https://jsfiddle.net/3usfa3ad/):

**HTML**

```html
<div id="XAxis" class="left" ></div>
<div id="YAxis" class="left" ></div>
<div id="XYAxis" class="right" ></div>
```

**CSS**

```css
div form p.left {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}
div form p.right {
    float: right;
    clear: both;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```js
var d3 = Plotly.d3;
var gd3 = d3.select("div[id='XAxis']");
var my_XAxis = gd3.node();
gd3 = d3.select("div[id='YAxis']");
var my_YAxis = gd3.node();
gd3 = d3.select("div[id='XYAxis']");
var my_XYAxis = gd3.node();

var layout = {
    xaxis: {
        range : [0, 1]
    },
    yaxis: {
        range : [0, 1]
    },
    margin: {t: 20},
    hovermode: 'closest',
}

Plotly.newPlot(my_XAxis, [], layout);
Plotly.newPlot(my_YAxis, [], layout);
Plotly.newPlot(my_XYAxis, [], layout);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `CSS` seems strange. Try changing it to:

```
div.left {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}
div.right {
    float: right;
    clear: both;
}
```

If you change the following block to

```
gd3 = d3.select("div[id='XYAxis']")
  .style({
    width: 0.5 * WIDTH_IN_PERCENT_OF_PARENT + '%',
    height: 1.5 * HEIGHT_IN_PERCENT_OF_PARENT + 'vh',
});
```

you should get the desired size changes for the third element.